# What extension do videos recorded from the native Blackberry video application have?

Tags: blackberry

When a video is taken using the native Blackberry video application, what extension do the videos have? So far I have seen .3gpp, but do other OS versions produce a different output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know video recorder on all RIM OS versions records video to .3gp container files. And video inside can be either in MPEG-4 or h.263 codec formats. By default BlackBerry device encodes recorded video with MPEG-4 codec.